# How to increase the value of one field with one request

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I'd like to make EF generate a SQL query like this:

```
UPDATE Users 
SET CurrentTurn = CurrentTurn + 1 
WHERE id = 1
```

In the current implementation I have to use two queries:

```
public void MakeTurn(int userId)
{
    var user = _storageContext.Users.Find(userId);
    user.CurrentTurn++;
    _storageContext.SaveChanges();
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CurrentTurn { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your SQL is two queries just like the c#.  So why do you expect the c# to be only one?

Comment: You need to get the object than update it, just as you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it in one DB roundtrip as far I know you'll need to install a 3rd party library like [EntityFramework-Plus](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus):

```
_storageContext.Users.Where(x => x.Id==userId)
               .Update(x => new User() { CurrentTurn = x.CurrentTurn+1 });
```

In the github page you will find the instruction about the nuget package you'll need to install, in you case is:

```
PM> Install-Package Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EFCore
```

If you want to see other options you can check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/), but I always have use the quoted library in cases like yours